# Why do i get an error in my MIPS code to convert Hexa to Binary?

Tags: hex, mips, cpu-architecture, mars-simulator

Hello can someone please help fix my code or see where the error is to fix it? I'm trying to convert a hexadecimal number to binary in MIPS but I keep getting an error when I try running it and have no idea where the error is or how to fix it.

My code:

```
.data

buffer: .space 8

prompt: .asciiz "\nInput a hexadecimal number: "

asnwer: .asciiz "\nBinary number is: "

.text

main: 

    la $a0, prompt 
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, buffer
    li $a1, 2 

    move $t0, $a0 
    syscall

hextodec: 

    slti $t0, $a0, 0x41
    beq $t0, $zero, letter
    addi $v0, $a0, -0x30

    j end

letter:

    addi $t0, $a0, -0x41
    addi $v0, $t0, 10

end:
    jr $a0
```

Comment: What error message, or what happens?  Without details like that, this isn't a [mcve].  Your loop looks like it's trying to convert to a binary integer, but you've named it `hextodec`.  You don't need to turn your input hex into a decimal string...  You don't even need to convert the whole number to a binary integer in a register, you could just convert each hex digit to 4 binary digits.

Comment: one obvious problem is that you fall through from the `addi` at the end of `letter` to `end:`.  You're missing a loop branch there.

Comment: I get an "Exception 6 [bad instruction address]" error message.

Comment: At which address?  Is it right after one of the instructions in the source code you show in your question?  If not, where is it?

Comment: it says error occurred at PC = 0x10010004

Comment: all it says is that error occurs at PC = 0x100100004

Answer (score 1):

> it says error occurred at PC = 0x10010004

You're doing `jr $a0`, not the usual **`jr $ra`** to return to the return-address in the link register.

The register-indirect jump sets `PC = $a0`, but `$a0` is still pointing to `buffer`, from the `la $a0, buffer`.

Comment: This is why you include error messages in the question: `0x10010004` gave me a clue it was at or near the start of a section because of the address being only 4 bytes past a round number.  The whole point of asking on the Internet is that experts can understand / get clues from error messages you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you much!

The error message is gone! But an answer doesn't show up. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CSmajor: yes, you're missing a loop branch, and you're missing a syscall to do anything with any result you might create.  And you're missing the rest of the loop body to do anything with the 4-bit integer you create.  I think you might actually be turning a hex digit in `$a0` into an integer in a register, but you're also not loading a byte from the buffer into `$a0`, so you're processing the low byte of the *address*.  Single-step through your code after writing a new part of it, to make sure it works the way you expect in the debugger before you write more.